# Selenium changing html on a page with python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div id="modalContent" style="opacity: 1; top: 35%;">
            </div>
```

Say I want to delete this on everytime I go to a particular website.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("some url")
#driver.removeelement("""<div id="modalContent" style="opacity: 1; top: 35%;">
        #</div>""")
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why did you modify your question after answer was accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you should execute some javascript on the DOM element. Here is how I would do it.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('modalContent').remove()")
```

Should work.